# Implementing class embedded in an interface

Tags: java, interface, implementation

Assume I have an interface with a class embedded in it (the purpose being that this interface must provide a 'type'.  The interface has some methods using that 'type'.  So, in file S.java, I have

```
public interface S {
    public class SType
    {
    }

    public abstract void f( SType a ); 
}
```

I want to implement this interface, and I try this, in file SS.java:

```
public final class SS implements S
{
    public class SType extends java.util.HashSet<Integer>
    {
    }

    public void f( SType a )
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

However, when I try to compile these files ("javac S.java SS.java"), I get the usual error message "SS is not abstract and does not override abstract method f(SType) in S" indicating that "f()" in the concrete class is not a proper implementation of "f()" in the interface.  Why?

Comment: Because you have defined another SType class in SS that is different from the SType class already defined in S. Why do you redefine that class? Using a static nested class is no different from using a top-level class.

Comment: The definition of SType in S is empty (and abstract).  My understanding was that, when implementing an interface, the embedded class must also be implemented, so I provided (in SS) a concrete class called SType.  So, apparently, that's where I went wrong.  But the intention was correct, wasn't it?  How to carry that our?

Comment: This understanding is wrong. The class is a class like any other class. If the interface method accepts an S.SType as argument, then all the implementation must also accept an S.SType as argument, otherwise they don't respect the contract of the interface.

Comment: JB Nizet: Thank you, that's perfectly clear.  Now, what if I declare `SType` in the interface not as a class, but as an interface (leaving everything else unchanged)?  Then the interface method accepts an argument obeying the `S.SType` interface, and since `SS.SType` in the implementation is an implementation of that interface, the code would make perfect sense to me.  Yet it results in the same error.

Comment: No. It still wouldn't make sense. An interface is a contract. This interface says: I have a function f that accepts an S.SType. But the implementation says: I have a function f that accepts something different: an SS.SType. Let's take a concrete example: A Road is an interface that has a function drive(Vehicle). It thus says: all  implementations of Road must accept any kind of Vehicle (Bicycle, Car, etc.). And you're trying to implement Road by defining a function drive(Submarine). A Submarine is not a Vehicle. Even if it was, a Road is supposed to accept all vehicles, not just submarines.

Comment: Thanks very much!  So my question got reduced to the following.  How does one code an interface that requires that all its implementations contain a number of functions and a number of classes so that some arguments of some of those functions are instances of the concrete classes in the implementation?  (I'm aware that one can keep these two separate, i.e., one could declare different blueprints for the functions and the classes, but then how would one express the dependency between them, i.e., the implementation of the functions depends on the implementation of the datatypes, and vice versa?)

Comment: You would need a generic class, but it's impossible to force each implementation to have its own concrete type.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
public final class SS implements S{


    public class SType extends java.util.HashSet<Integer>
    {
    }

    public void f(S.SType a) {
        // ..
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Perhaps, you need this:

```
public interface S<SType> {
    public void f( SType a ); 
}

public final class SS implements S<HashSet<Integer>> {

    public void f(HashSet<Integer> a ){
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the files compile that way, but the following problem arises.  When I try to use the argument (`a`) in the implementation of `f()`, assuming that it is an instance of `SS.SType` (e.g., by using `HashSet` methods), the compiler complains.

Comment: @LászlóKálmán I Edited

Comment: Thanks, David, the latter version works fine.  However, this has a price: `SType` must be defined outside the interface.  I still wonder if it is possible for an interface to require that its implementations should provide their own implementations of a certain abstract class (or interface).